# Wordpress on Local very slow to see changes

Tags: css, wordpress, xampp, themes

I'm creating a new Wordpress theme on local (XAMPP). When I make changes in the theme folder in the wp-content folder, it takes a LONG time to be able to see these changes reflected on the localhost site. I cleared the cache, restarted xampp and even the computer. Still, sometimes, I can only see the changes the next day. The changes can be as simple as disable some jquery or changing the css. Is there some configuration issue at play? How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: When you meant that you cleared the cache, was it the Wordpress (server side) cache or the browser cache or both ?

Comment: Both server side and browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

- If you use any caching plugins try and disable them or purge cache.
- Try empty cache and hard reload on your browser.
- Try disabling all plugins and see if problem still exists.
- Try changing theme and see if problem still exists.

Comment: When I changed theme, I did see the site updated immediately.

Comment: So you know its the theme you develop that is problematic. Are you using versioning on scripts and styles on functions.php? If yes update the versioning there every time you do any changes.

Comment: Hi, I tried out everything. Only the CSS seems VERY SLOW to update. When I wake up next morning, it'd be updated. I'm guessing I would have to restart the PC. I don't know why. I'm using SASS, but it was the same situation when I just used CSS.